# Using sed to capture the first word with capital letters

Tags: unix, sed, extract

I am interested in retrieving first word in a sentence if it begins with 5 capital letters. For example, if a sentence is `SOLAR eclipse`, I need `SOLAR`. If the sentence is `SOLA eclipse` or `solar ECLIPSE` or `40 thieves`, then nothing.

```
printf "SOLAR eclipse\nSOLA eclipse\nsolar ECLIPSE\n40 thieves" | sed 's/\(^[A-Z]\{5\}\).*/\1/'
SOLAR
SOLA eclipse
solar ECLIPSE
40 thieves
```

As we see, the extraction works for the first sentence only. I had expected it would return empty string for the second, third and fourth, but it returns the whole string.

Comment: because the default `sed` action is to print the pattern space, whether substitution or any other command was used and they worked or not.. you can use `-n` to prevent that and use `p` to print only when you want.. `sed -n 's/\(^[A-Z]\{5\}\).*/\1/p'`

Comment: Are you limited to only using sed regex?

Comment: note that this would work for more than 5 letters too, for example `SOLARIS foo`.. and you could use `grep -o '^[A-Z]\{5\}'` too

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I am not. Digvijay has a nice simplified solution with simple grep! Thanks to you also Sundeep.

Comment: Were you after `read -r one two three four <<< $(printf "SOLAR eclipse\nSOLA eclipse\nsolar ECLIPSE\n40 thieves" | sed 's/^\([A-Z]\{5\}\)\{0,1\}.*/\1/')`? See [demo](https://ideone.com/EhRdRo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using grep

```
$printf  "SOLAR eclipse\nSOLA eclipse\nsolar ECLIPSE\n40 thieves" | grep -oE  '^[A-Z]{5}'
SOLAR
$
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` could you please try following too.

```
printf "SOLAR eclipse\nSOLA eclipse\nsolar ECLIPSE\n40 thieves" |
awk 'match($0,/^[A-Z]{5}/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```